# ASP.NET MVC 5 safely render html from model?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xss, antixsslibrary

I'm new to ASP.NET and web development in general. But I've heard a lot of things about how unsafe rendering HTML directly can be due to things like XSS attacks. But I'm working on a project where I'm dynamically selecting a set of static strings and replacing parts of them with a name that should be in a bold font and color. For example a string could be:

> the lazy {1} jumped over the quick brown {2}

And then names and styles are inserted. Something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
String.Replace("{1}", "<b style='color:someColor;'>fox</b>")
String.Replace("{2}", "<b style='color:someColor2;'>dog</b>")
```

Then I want to display that string with HTML rendering in a view. I've seen that it can be done with @Html.Raw() or similar methods. But my question is this safe? If not, is there another way to do it or at least emulate the end result in a safe manner?

Comment: Just asking: why not this?....`the lazy <b style='color:someColor;'>{1} </b>jumped over the quick brown <b style='color:someColor2;'>{2}</b>` And only pass the fox/dog...this way you wont need `Html.Raw()`

Comment: @SamGhatak The string isn't static, and a non pre-determined amount of strings will be put after each other so I can't statically put it in the view.

Comment: for XSS security, you need to differentiate the data you receive as a text from user from other data....for, say the NAME of the user...this should not be displayed using `Html.Raw()` , but for colors or such data, that are not taken from the users as a text form can be used in `Html.Raw()` if required...in another way....you can validate the data given by the users if those contain any markup, and accept only harmless data

Comment: @SamGhatak so as long as I don't render any user inputted strings, only strings I generate from within my application that I know are safe, I should be good? The only user inputted strings I receive are required to be only English letters anyway.

Comment: Yes, that checking on user inputted strings should be good enough....just be careful about some unsuspecting bugs like keeping unnecessary hidden input fields...where the user can hit F12 and play with the values...the application might not consider them as user input and save without verifying...just be careful in such scenarios...